# sentry why I dont see my error result I only see the console log

Tags: node.js, sentry

I want to see the error but it does not show on sentry.

I see exact this code:

```
     Sentry.captureException(`
        Error: @Inngest Create Product Function
        -------------
        Param Error: ${error},
      `)
    }
```

So it does not show the error variable
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EUW3.png)